# How to convert ajax response to pdf document in php jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mpdf

> I am using php and jquery to display data and create pdf file with
> mpdf libary. But pdf is not generated please help me with the same.My
> sample code is below:

abc.php

```
<a onclick=getData()>CLICK ME</a>;
```

Ajax Call :

```
function getData(){
  $.ajax({url: "employee/getEmpData", success: function(result){
     window.open(result, "_blank");
  }});
}
```

PHP :

```
function getEmpData(){
     $sqlquery = ////;
     SELF::generatePDF($sqlquery);
}

function generatePDF($sqlquery){
   //mpdf stuff
}
```

First onclick Anchor tag it will go to ajax call then it will go to particular function to fetch data from db `getEmpData()` then it will go to `generatePDF()`.
In ajax response i am getting proper binary data from mpdf.
but i dont know how to convert this data to generate pdf in ajax response.

Comment: Why are you using Ajax in the first place if you want to have a PDF? Just use a link.

Comment: you need return generated data. Add return keyword ... return SELF::generatePDF($sqlquery);

Comment: pdf is a file so you should not return binary data but pdf file with proper headers like @Quentin said. Just link without ajax.

Comment: This is a really bizarre way to do this task, it should be much simpler. You don't need AJAX. Instead just make the JavaScript open a link to the script which returns the binary data directly. If you set the correct headers in the response then the browser will treat it as a PDF file automatically.